# How to pin WiFi settings on the start screen?

Tags: settings, wifi, pin-to-start

Is there a way to pin a shortcut to the WiFi settings on the start screen? It's just one extra click, but sometimes I need it really fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an app called [Connectivity Shortcuts](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/430cf007-731f-4357-af7b-b897bff25a2c) that will allow you to pin a tile to get to your wi-fi settings from your homescreen.

Comment: I will, it says "You can accept an answer in X minutes", where X currently is 5.

Comment: Oh Ok! Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

As demonstrated on the newly announced Lumia 640 and 640 XL, Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2 will add the ability to pin individual settings to the Start screen, obviating the need for third-party apps.

For more information, see [this article at Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/pin-individual-settings-gdr2).